# How to get range of characters between @ and caret in contenteditable

Tags: javascript, contenteditable, caret

I have a contenteditable div and it contains other tags and not only plain text. Only one @ is allowed in. How can I get the range of the characters between @ and caret if such a range exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ha that was easier than I thought!. Based on this easy to overlook question: [Div "contenteditable" : get and delete word preceding caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24890130/div-contenteditable-get-and-delete-word-preceding-caret) I forked its jsfiddle and here is mine working as expected:

http://jsfiddle.net/52m2thu2/1/

```
function getWordBetweenAtAndCaret(containerEl) {
    var preceding = "",
        sel,
        range,
        precedingRange;
    if (window.getSelection) {
        sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.collapse(true);
            range.setStart(containerEl, 0);
            preceding = range.toString();
        }
    } else if ((sel = document.selection) && sel.type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        precedingRange = range.duplicate();
        precedingRange.moveToElementText(containerEl);
        precedingRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        preceding = precedingRange.text;
    }
    var lastWord = preceding.match(/@(.+)$/i);
    if (lastWord) {
        return lastWord;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```