# finding focus of cursor in radeditor

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik, radeditor

I am using radeditor in my project.
I want the text which is immediate after the cursor position or immediate before the cursor position.

I can set html using editor.pasteHtml("html") but how can I get the text before or after that position?

Answer (score 0):

In short you should create a range in the content area of RadEditor

```
var range = editor.getSelection().getRange();
```

and obtain the content selection. Try the solution provided in this forum thread: [pasteHtml After Node at Cursor Position?](http://www.telerik.com/forums/pastehtml-after-node-at-cursor-position).

You can find additional information about the ranges in these articles:

http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/JavaScript-DOM-Ranges-Page-2.id-292302.html
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28VS.85%29.aspx

Once you create a range in the editor, you can use the GetCaretPosition function from this thread: [JavaScript get word before cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959690/javascript-get-word-before-cursor)

Comment: I want to get text which is before & after cursor position. Not set text.

Comment: Once you create a range in the editor, you can use the GetCaretPosition function from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959690/javascript-get-word-before-cursor